# How do I save my project into Xcode from an external drive?

Tags: xcode

I saved my xcode project and files onto an external thumb drive because I had to put a new hard drive in my computer and reinstall the operating system and xcode.
Now when I connect the drive and open the file from the drive window, it will open the project in xcode. I tried to click save in the xcode file menu but when I tak out the external drive the project disappears in the xcode window.
How do I save the project into Xcode so it stays there after I remove my external drive.
I'm still very new and I'm sure this is easy but I can't figure it out. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply drag and drop your project folder to your internal hard drive, then open the project from there.

Comment: I can open the project from the thumb drive and it seems to open it in xcode. But I can't seem to save it into xcode so it shows up when the thumbdrive is not in. I'm not following what you're saying, sorry I'm really not great with this stuff.

Comment: Okay, close your Xcode. Go back to finder. Drag and drop the Xcode project file and the folder containing it to your hard drive. Then open your project by double clicking the project in your hard drive.

Comment: When I try to open from the HD the project opens and the file names are all there but they are red. So the underlying file is not actually there. However if I open the xcode project out of the finder when I am in the external drive it brings up the whole project with all the complete files and code. Is there some way to just save it from there into my developer folder the same way I would if I was starting a new project in xcode?

Comment: Except for the file is like 3GB this is not efficient.